# Homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism for reduced homology groups

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is an exercise from Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) book:

**Exercise 2.1.13, pg. 132:** Verify that $f≃g$ implies $f_∗=g_∗$ for induced homomorphisms of reduced homology groups.

**The formal version of the exercise:** If $f,g :(X,A) \to (Y,B)$ are homotopic, then $f_* = g_*:H_n(X,A) \to H_n(Y,B)$.

Is there any gap in the sequence of the proof?

**Proof:** By Theorem 2.10, we know that if two maps $f,g :X \to Y$ are homotopic, then they induce the same homomorphism $f_* = g_*:H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$.

So, the prism operator $P:C_n(X) \to C_{n+1}(Y)$ satisfying $\partial P +P \partial =g_\# - f_\#$ clearly sends $C_n(A)$ to $C_{n+1}(B)$.

Thus, $P$ gives a natural prism operator on quotients, i.e., $\tilde{P}: C_n(X,A) \to C_{n+1}(Y,B)$ s.t. $\partial P +P \partial =g_\# - f_\#$.

Therefore $f_*=g_*: H_n(X,A) \to H_n(Y,B).$

Comment: where does this come from: the prism operator $P:C_n(X) \to C_{n+1}(Y)$ satisfying $\partial P +P \partial =g_\# - f_\#$, This is because P are homotopic?